# Laravel Auth successfully logged in but keep redirecting to login page and not showing failed error flash message

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to authenticate user login with username and password in Laravel 8 (manual auth). I can't go to next page after logged in and it kept stuck on login page. This is the auth function:

```
public function authenticate(Request $request) {
        $credentials = $request->validate([
            'username' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        if(Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();
            return redirect()->intended('/')->with('loginSuccess', 'Welcome back!');
        };

        return back()->with('loginError', 'Login failed.');
    }
```

My table is `users`, with the PK is `UserId`, and then it has `Username` and `Password` columns. I have tried to override `username()` function in my `LoginController.php`:

```
public function username() {
        return 'Username';
    }
```

and also changing `getAuth...()`  functions in `User.php` model:

```
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->attributes['UserId'];
    }

    public function getAuthIdentifierName()
    {
        return 'Username';
    }

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->attributes['Password'];
        // return 'Password';
    }
```

What prevents my app to auth the user? Big thanks!!

p.s. there seems to be a new link appeared after i named my route for `logout()` in `LoginController.php`:

```
public function logout(Request $request) {
        Auth::logout();
        $request->session()->invalidate();
        $request->session()->regenerateToken();
        return view('/login');
    }
```

```
protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login');
        }
    }
```

[No error flash message after login process in Laravel manual auth and a new link on the left side after naming a route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGFdr.png)

edit: i found that the auth trying to find a user using query `SELECT * FROM` users`WHERE`Username `= 'UserId' LIMIT 1`
[dd($request) result and clockwork screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iuovq.png)

Comment: WHY do you regenerate the session after logging in?

Comment: Is the problem because you changed the column name `id` to `UserId`?

Comment: @Snapey sorry i have no idea and i'm just following a tutorial, should i remove it?

Comment: @Lucas i have changed the `protected $primaryKey = 'UserId';` and my app still has the same problem

Comment: Add a `dd('ok');` right after `$request->session()->regenerate();` and when you login see if it returns the text (to see if it is actually logging in ).

Comment: @Lucas the result is `"ok"` i think it's okay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that my `getAuthIndentifier()` method that was later modified to:

```
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return 'UserId';
    }
```

causing the trouble that the query changed to `` SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `Username` = 'UserId' LIMIT 1 ``. So i had to turn the method to comment and my username input can be read to the query again. Thank you!!

[successful auth with the right query for the logged in user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HWEX.png)